# Receive TCP RST packet from unreachable computer

Tags: tcp, wireshark, ehostunreach

I had an opportunity to work with wireshark.

I installed wireshark on my VMware and made some tests on it, I found an interesting thing.

I sent the HTTP request to non-existing computer and captured all the packet flow with wireshark.

The first packet was SYN packet, the second one was re-transmission packet.(the system hadn't received any response from the targeted computer).

But surprisingly, RST packet from the target computer reached.

I couldn't understand where this packet came from, so I tested for 2 target computers, and in both cases, I had the RST packet.

So are there anyone who can tell me about those suspicious RST packets?

Thanks for reading.

Regards.

https://ask.wireshark.org/upfiles/img2_fpJSr9b.png
https://ask.wireshark.org/upfiles/img3_Rxmvejp.png

Comment: Check the source MAC address of those packets and you'll likely see that it's from your default gateway.

Comment: @Zac67 MAC is always re-written by gateway, so no matter who sends this packet, it will always have source MAC of default gateway.

Comment: Sure - just wanted to show that these RSTs don't magically (and suspiciously) originate in the local network.